# How to crop UIImage in ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage

[image]

I have an `UIImageView` taking the whole screen except navigation bar. Besides, I have an `UIView` with red border on top of `UIImageView`. When "Done" button is clicked, I want image inside red border being cropped.

I tried hard to use `CGImage.cropping(to: rect)`. But the rect I sent is just frame of `UIView` with red border, which is different from rect of a `cgImage`.

How could I send proper 'rect' parameter into cropping(to: rect)method of `CGImage` instance to crop Image?

Comment: u need to convert the rect on your View into a rect proportional to your UIImage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617676/scale-and-crop-image-ios

Comment: Have a look at the post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage

Answer (score 2):

Place the `UIImageView` inside a `UIView` of the same size.  Set for the container view's `clipsToBounds = YES`.  When you want to make the image smaller change the frame of the `UIView` to be the frame of that red frame and change the origin of the frame of the `UImageView` to be the negative of the origin of the red frame. You can also easily animate this effect if you want by putting it in an animation block

Comment: But I need to get a cropped UIImage and store it somewhere else.